# Recommendation needed for running cron in replicated services

Tags: kubernetes, cron

If let's say my service is running cron jobs. But the service replica is set to 2 in the Kubernetes, this will cause the cron job to run twice at each schedule.
Is there any design recommendation to prevent this?
Should we only have 1 replicas for a cron job running services or is there any other way?

Comment: Is it specifically a Spring Boot application; [Run Scheduled Cron method in Spring from single pod if multiple pods exist on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528489/run-scheduled-cron-method-in-spring-from-single-pod-if-multiple-pods-exist-on-ku)?  Can you use a Kubernetes CronJob rather than a scheduler in your application?

Comment: No, i am using Golang robfig/cron. We are currently using K8s CronJobs, we want to get rid of that.

Comment: @MohamadArafat Were you able to find the best solution? Could you please share?

Comment: @saneMan, I used leader election mechanism. In my case, only leader pod will run the cron job. I refer from here to do the leader election: https://carlosbecker.com/posts/k8s-leader-election/

Comment: @MohamadArafat Any reason for not using k8s Cronjobs? What were the issues you were facing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a known standard, but I solved it using a locking mechanism on a database (or any other storage means, for that matter).
The cron functions will have a lock-checking mechanism such that:

- the cron operation should have a random delay of some small amount of time so that all the replicas will start the cron at a slightly different time.
- when a cron starts, it checks if the cron status is in a locked state (on the database/storage). if it is locked, then it will skip the operation. if it is not locked, it locks the state, executes the operation, and unlocks the state afterward.

with this setup, you can be sure that only one replica of the service will actually run the cron operation.